# Route 53 - CloudFront : Network Error (dns_server_failure)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I deployed a frontend in a Cloudfront distribution and it is working fine for all users. Although when I created an Alias record in the Route 53 poiting to the Cloudfront endpoint (that is working) some users can find the site, but some are experiencing the following error:

> Network Error (dns_server_failure) Your request could not be processed
> because an error occurred contacting the DNS server. The DNS server
> may be temporarily unavailable, or there could be a network problem.

It's been two or three days since the first deploy, so it is already propagated, and I already checked the name servers in the host zone and the record and they actually match. I don't know what else to try... Any idea?

Comment: What is the result of using this one to check on your site - https://dnschecker.org?

Comment: The weird thing is that it says it works everywhere but Brazil (my country) lol